# Output stylesheets only for specific entry points in Webpack without any script generation?

Tags: webpack, webpack-2

I have multiple entry points in my webpack config for login, app, error pages, I only require login and app to output a js file for these entries and error to only output styles. At the moment all the entries output both styles and scripts and I'm not overly sure how to be specific with what gets output?

**Webpack**

```
entry: {
    'main': [
        'babel-polyfill',
        './source/styles/src/imports/main/main.scss',
        './source/app/app.main.js'
    ],
    'login': [
        './source/styles/src/imports/login/login.scss',
        './source/scripts/login.js'
    ],
    'errors': './source/styles/src/imports/errors/errors.scss'
},

output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: './scripts/[name]/[name].min.js',
    chunkFilename: './scripts/chunks/[id].[name].min.js'
}
```

**Outputs**

```
dist/
    scripts/
        errors/ <---- doesn't need to be here
        main/
        login/
    styles/
         errors/
         main/
         login/
```

Can anyone suggest how I can exclude errors from being output in scripts?

Answer (score 6):

Webpack create separate file for each `key` present in your entry object

**the `key` of entry object decide `name` of separate file to create and `value` of that key decide what `content` to include in that file**

if you dont want to create a separate file but include it's content in you bundle then just add path of this file in your previous entry

for example

```
entry: {
  main: ['src/js/main.js'],
  app: ['src/js/app.js']
}
```

will create two seprate file 1.`main.js` and 2.`app.js` with there respective content

and

```
entry: {
  main: ['src/js/main.js', 'src/js/app.js']
}
```

will create one file `main.js` (because the key of entry object is called `main`) with the content of both file included in it

and

```
entry: {
  app: ['src/js/main.js', 'src/js/app.js']
}
```

will aslo create one file `app.js` (because the key of entry object is called `app`) with the content of both file included in it

so if you don't want to create separate errors file but include it's content then don't add errors property on `entry` object

then your configration will be like

```
entry: {
    'main': [
        'babel-polyfill',
        './source/styles/src/imports/main/main.scss',
        './source/app/app.main.js',
        './source/styles/src/imports/errors/errors.scss' <--- so that webpack know to include content of that file also
    ],
    'login': [
        './source/styles/src/imports/login/login.scss',
        './source/scripts/login.js'
    ]
}
```

**also note that you need to use either the `style-loader` or `extract-text-webpack-plugin` to separate `css` content from your JavaScript file**

to create independent `errors.css` file you need to use two different instance of `extract-text-wepack-plugin` one for regular css file and one for errors.css file and use `include` `exclude` property to seprate

```
    const extractCSS = new ExtractTextPlugin('main.css');
    const extractERRORS = new ExtractTextPlugin('errors.css');
    . 
    .
    .
module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        exclude: /errors/,
        use: extractCSS.extract([ 'css-loader', 'sass-loader' ])
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        include: /errors/,
        use: extractERRORS.extract([ 'css-loader', 'sass-loader' ])
      },
    ]
  },

      plugins: [
       extractCSS,
       extractERRORS
      ]
```

Comment: Hey so I need errors.css to be independent but I don't need errors.js, so that's my main question - how can this be done without outputting js? I am using ExtractTextPlugin to create the files which uses the entry name new ExtractTextPlugin('styles/[name]/[name].min.css'),

Comment: to create independent errors.css file you need to use two different instance of extract-text-wepack-plugin one for regular css file and one for errors.css file

Comment: sure just wait i will show you . you have to use include and exclude property on loader

Answer (score 0):

You can use this webpack plugin: [webpack-fix-style-only-entries](https://github.com/fqborges/webpack-fix-style-only-entries)

It finds js files from chunks of css only entries and remove the js file from the compilation.

Just add to your webpack.config like this:

```
// ... other plugins
const FixStyleOnlyEntriesPlugin = require("webpack-fix-style-only-entries");

module.exports = {
    // ...
    plugins: [
        new FixStyleOnlyEntriesPlugin(),
    ],
};
```